# What is difference between LogManager.GetLogger("Name") and LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()?

Tags: c#, logging, web-applications, nlog

Can anybody explain me in detail? searched online but didn't get satisfactory anwer. I am logging in csv file with NLog. `LogManager.GetLogger` method works fine but if I will use `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` it is not working. why is that?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? `ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`

Comment: yes, I am not able to log with "private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();"

Answer (score 6):

`LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` will search in the stacktrace of the call to find out the full class name (so namespace and class name) of the caller.

The full class name will be used as logger name.

The relevant code in `LogManager`

```cs
public static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger()
{
   return factory.GetLogger(StackTraceUsageUtils.GetClassFullName());
}
```

So if you invoke `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` inside `MyNamespace.MyClass`, you will get a `Logger` with name "MyNamespace.MyClass"